# How to create a double sided sunburst chart in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

Wondering if anyone can help me with this visualisation requirement.

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID, VOLUME, AGE
95001, 231, 15
27024, 352, 9
90404, 421, 11
90483, 213, 30
```

I want to visualise the data in a sunburst chart, with outward burst represents the volume of an entity and inward burst represents the age of an entity.

Has anyone done a visualisation similar to this? It can be from Plotly or any other python based visualisation toolkit.

Comment: I Googled `plotly sunburst` and it led me to [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/). Presumably you found it too. Did you try it? If so, what happened? If not, give it a go and come back to edit your question if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Matt, yes, i've been playing with plotly sunburst chart for a while, and that's not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a ring chart, with radiation spikes coming from both sides of the ring (the length of the outward spike represent the volume, and the length of the inward spike represent the age)

Comment: I'd never heard of a 'sunburst chart' until I read your post, and everything in Google image search looks like the ones Plotly produces. So if you have something else in mind, the best thing would be to post an example showing exactly what you have in mind.